# calculate the relation between two names in percentage

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an application which takes in two names and calculates the love percentage between them.
 I have taken the Strings LOVE,firstname and lastname in an character array but i am not able to decide what to do     next.Nothing on the internet is providing me the start or an algorithm.Please point me to some sites where i can get  the algo for this...THanks...Following is my code for taking the string name in a character array

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText Fname,Sname;
Button btn;
char[] L_array,F_array,S_array;
int sum=0;
int sum2=0;
String love = "LOVES";
String first_name,second_name;
private String name1;
private String name2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name1);
    Sname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name2);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OkButton);

    L_array = new char[love.length()];

    for(int count=0;count <L_array.length;count++){
        L_array[count] = love.charAt(count);
        Log.e("character array", L_array[count]+ " ");
    }

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            first_name = Fname.getText().toString();
            second_name = Sname.getText().toString();

            Log.e("FirstPerson", Fname.getText().toString());
            Log.e("SecondPerson", Sname.getText().toString());

            F_array = new char[Fname.length()];
            S_array = new char[Sname.length()];

            for(int count = 0; count <F_array.length;count++){

                F_array[count] = first_name.charAt(count);
                Log.e("first_name", F_array[count]+ " ");
            }

            for(int count = 0; count <S_array.length;count++){

                S_array[count] = second_name.charAt(count);
                Log.e("second_name",S_array[count]+ " ");
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link to get an idea about how to calculate love percentage... You can implement your algorithm on the basis of the given logic.

[Love Calculation Logic](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_calculate_a_love_percentage#slide2)